# Error "The URI 'XY' is not valid because it is not based on 'XY'" in LogicApp call from JS

Tags: javascript, azure-logic-apps, microsoft-dynamics, azure-http-trigger, xrmquery

I never had an eror like this so I am hoping someboday has a hint regarding this.

I call an HTTP triggered Azure Logic App with javascript by using the XrmQuery.SendRequest() method like this:

```
XrmQuery.sendRequest("POST", url, JSON.stringify(queryPayload),
  function (result) {
     showAlertDialog("blabla");
  },
  function (error) {
     console.log("Error", error);
     showAlertDialog("blablabla" + error);
});
```

This script is executed within an Dynamics 365 environment.

the url of the logic app is as follows:

> https://xxx.germanywestcentral.logic.azure.com:443/workflows/00000000006942109e13ce0e9c1c4112/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-10-01&sp=%2Ftriggers%2Fmanual%2Frun&sv=1.0&sig=wzedGSO9vs5pfcDQ9WP0qdc5UBGTU2b-kqbWO8x051E

The error I get is the following:

> Error: {"error":{"code":"0x8006088a","message":"The URI
> 'https://ORGANIZATION_XY.crm4.dynamics.com/aaaa/workflows/00000000000000000013ce0e9c1c4112/triggers/manual/paths/invoke?api-version=2016-10-01&sp=/triggers/manual/run&sv=1.0&sig=wzedGSO9vs5pfcDQ9WP0qdc5UBGTU2b-kqbWO8x051E'
> is not valid because it is not based on
> 'https://ORGANIZATION_XY.crm4.dynamics.com/api/data/v8.0/'."}}

When I call the LogicApp via Postman it works fine. As soon I execute the js code which calls the logic app within Dynamics I get this error.

Anybody knows what this error means?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In simple words **"0x8006088a"** error code means **bad request**.  It says that the request isn’t correct, because there is an error in query syntax. That’s what you should focus on. There might be some issue with the query string or even the version of the API.

Also note that the **Dynamics 365 connector** is deprecated but not removed yet. Do not use the Dynamics 365 connector for new logic apps, For connections to Dynamics 365, use the **Common Data Service connector**.